# $1+xy+yz+xz-x-y-z>0$ where $x,y,z \in (0,1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

> $f(x,y,z)=1+xy+yz+xz-x-y-z$, where $x,y,z \in (0,1)$.  Show that:
>   $f(x,y,z)>0$.

$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y+z-1=0 \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x+z-1=0 \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=x+y-1=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$

This linear equations has only one solution: $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$,

The Hessian of $f$ is $$\begin{vmatrix}0&&1&&1\\
1&&0&&1\\
1&&1&&0\end{vmatrix}$$. It is neither positive define nor negative define. I failed.

Comment: Nah, failing is showing no work and expecting an answer. You stumbled.

Comment: in case you can't make sure the critical points, check the bound,since they are symmetry,you only need to check (1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1). all 4 points show $f(x)>0$. then you can say it is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, $$f(x,y,z)=(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)+xyz$$ so since both terms are positive ($x,y,z\in(0,1)$ so all factors of both terms are positive), $$f(x,y,z)>0$$